# UTF-8 characters in python string even after decoding from UTF-8?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, utf-8

I'm working on converting portions of XHTML to JSON objects. I finally got everything in JSON form, but some UTF-8 character codes are being printed.
Example:

```
{
  "p": {
    "@class": "para-p",
    "#text": "I\u2019m not on Earth."
  }
}
```

This should be:

```
{
  "p": {
    "@class": "para-p",
    "#text": "I'm not on Earth."
  }
}
```

This is just one example of UTF-8 codes coming through. How can I got through the string and replace every instance of a UTF-8 code with the character it represents?

Comment: what we have here is a <right single quotation mark>  (\u2019) that should be replaced by  <apostrophe> (\u27). do you have also some other unwanted characters that needs to be replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\u2019` is not a UTF-8 character, but a Unicode escape code.  It's valid JSON and when read back via `json.load` will become `’` (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK).

If you want to write the actual character, use `ensure_ascii=False` to prevent escape codes from being written for non-ASCII characters:

```py
with open('output.json','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn'T paste your code, so I don't kwon how you converted XHTML to JSON. I assume that you ended with hex value characters in Python objects. This `\u2019` is a single character with a 16-bit hex value. The JSON module can handle this by default.  For example, the `json.loads` method can fix that:

```
x = '''{
  "p": {
    "@class": "para-p",
    "#text": "I\\u2019m not on Earth."
  }
}'''

print(x)
x_json=json.loads(x)
print(x_json)
```

Output shows:

```
{
  "p": {
    "@class": "para-p",
    "#text": "I\u2019m not on Earth."
  }
}

{'p': {'@class': 'para-p', '#text': 'I’m not on Earth.'}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Ok, I rewrite it from scratch.